# Surface Pro (1) Mini Display Port VGA - Windows 10

Tags: drivers, windows-10, multiple-monitors, windows-10-upgrade

Anyone have luck getting the Microsoft Mini Display Port VGA Adapter working on the *original* Surface Pro and Windows 10? It did work on Windows 8 on another Surface Pro but I upgraded one to Windows 10 (it wasn't tested for the mini display ort VGA working before the upgrade) and the Control Panel - Display dialog does not show the second monitor. Detect doesn't do anything.

Windows-P reports it can't Project and suggests to update the driver - but drivers for the VGA adapter are not to be found (by me) on the Microsoft site.

Only Windows 10 + Surface help page I could find mentions all version of Surface Pro except the original. Is this device even supported on Windows 10?

Comment: I have the original Surface Pro the adapter works for me.

Comment: Did you upgrade to Windows 10?

Comment: Of course I did

Answer (score 0):

Problem resolved. Automatic Updates was stuck and needed a reset. After that two hardware updates came down. The device now works.

FYI The StarTech triple adapter works now as well - it didn't a long time ago but it does now.